# ModalPopupExtender close itself

Tags: c#, jquery, html, asp.net, ajax

I used ModalPopupExtender to popup a panel. In the panel I have a textbox. For that textbox's textchanged event i'm wrote some codes. But whenever focus come out of that textbox. 
The popup is closing itself immediately. Can anyone say how to resolve this issue.

```
 <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:Panel ID="pnlEdit" runat="server" Width="100%"
DefaultButton="lnkbtnCancel">

<table id="tblEditUser">
                                          <tr>
                                        <td><asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="E-mail:" CssClass="lblGray"></asp:Label></td>
                                        <td colspan="2"><asp:TextBox ID="txtEmail" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"   ontextchanged="txtEmail_TextChanged" CssClass="txtDarkgray" Width="300px"></asp:TextBox></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td><asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Name:" CssClass="lblGray"></asp:Label></td>
                                        <td><asp:Label ID="lblName" runat="server" CssClass="lblGray"></asp:Label></td>
                                   </tr>
```

Comment: Try to put it under update panel. So postback will not close your ModalPopupExtender

Comment: its already in update panel. Kindly need your help to solve this problem.

Comment: Edit your post and add code.

Comment: post your modalpopup extender code here..!!!

Comment: <asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="pnlEdit_ModalPopupExtender" runat="server" BackgroundCssClass="modal_blue" Enabled="True" 
            PopupControlID="pnlEdit" TargetControlID="btnShowUserInfo" CancelControlID="btnClose">
        </asp:ModalPopupExtender>

Comment: do anyone advise????

Comment: @user3785636 Add pnlEdit_ModalPopupExtender.Show() at the bottom of textbox's textchanged event. And let me know

Comment: yes done.but still same problem.

Answer (score 0):

May you please post some code which you are doing.
I think this may help

write following code on text change event of textbox:

ModalPopUpExtenderName.Show();

Please revert if it does not help also mark as answer if it does help.
Happy Coding:)

Comment: You could have posted it as comment and not as an answer

Comment: @RahulNikate He cant because of the reputation...and Navnit...If you are starting @ SO then learn the basics first as how to Post an answer

Comment: Thanks for suggestion @Tushar Gupta, i'll keep in my mind while answering.
My suggestion is only that write ModalPopUpExtenderName.Show()
at the bottom of text_change code of texbox

Comment: @user3785636 Please write code of textbox's textchanged event,
it would be helpful to help to you.